# Read File from resources folder when code is in external jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, jar, classpath

I am working on creating a library(it will be a jar file). I have a running application "A" which has a dependency on this lib I am creating- "B.jar".
Inside src/resources folder of A, we have a file eg."test.yaml".
B has some code which is to be called from A and the file path passed as string alongwith. Code in B should be able to read the file content and do further processing..

Here is my code in lib "B"

```
private TestDataVO getTestDataVO(String testFileName) {

        InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(this.testFileName);
                testData = ymlMapper.readValue(is, TestDataVO.class);

            
        return testData;
    }
```

The caller code in "A":

`getTestDataVO("test.yaml")`

The problem with my code is the this.getClass.getClassLoader() gives classpath of "B" rather than "A" and thus not able to read test.yaml which is on "A" 's classpath. How can I can modify getTestDataVO to read the file from "A"'s classpath. Sending absolute path is not an option. I 'll be happy to clarify any further.

PS.- I have tried searching for other answers, all of which point to resource file present in jar and reading from calling application. I am trying the other way around-file in calling application, to be read from jar's context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getTestDataVO` code doesn't care how it gets its data, as long as it gets it.

Hence, the correct parameter type of `getTestDataVO` **is not `String`**. Instead it should be `byte[]`, or `InputStream`, or possibly both.

Also note that what you're doing so far is wrong (it's `MyClass.class.getResource`, not `getClass().getClassLoader()...`. The `getClassLoader()` part is pointless typing and breaks in rare circumstances. `getClass()` breaks when subclassing. Hence why that's the only correct way for this kind of task).

Let's say you make that inputstream. Then you can do:

```
private TestDataVO getTestDataVO(InputStream is) {
   try {
     testData = ymlMapper.readValue(is, TestDataVO.class);
   } finally {
     is.close();
   }
}

// and to call:
  getTestDataVO(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("test.yaml"));
```

Or possibly even by using just `getResource`:

```
private TestDataVO getTestDataVO(URL resource) {
   try (var is = resource.openStream()) {
     testData = ymlMapper.readValue(is, TestDataVO.class);
   }
}

// and to call:
  getTestDataVO(MyClass.class.getResource("test.yaml"));
```

In both of those the crucial aspect is that **A** ends up using *its* loader to find this resource, and then passes the found resource to B, instead of asking B to find it which is tricky as it's part of A's classpath, not B's.

---

EDIT:

A second idea, but I *strongly* recommend against this:

```
private TestDataVO getTestDataVO(Class<?> context, String resource) {
   try (var is = context.getResourceAsStream(resource)) {
     testData = ymlMapper.readValue(is, TestDataVO.class);
   }
}

// to call:

class Example {
  void foo() {
    testDataTool.getTestDataVO(Example.class, "/my/resource.txt");
  }
}
```

This is the closest equivalent of 'I just want callers to pass in a string'. You can do that.. if you *also* pass along the class to use as 'context' - use *this class's loader architecture to load this resource*. There is no way to get, not even from a stack trace, the `java.lang.Class` instance representing 'the class whose code called me' in case that's where you're thinking is heading.

Comment: Hi @rzwitserloot, Thanks for your answer. I know I can pass the file as inputStream, in fact the whole file content as String as  well. That was my contingency plan if this does not work out, but as of now I want to pass just the file path/name and let my lib do the rest. That makes all of my calling code(here its A) look clean. Like you said, asking B to find file is tricky, but if its possible, I want to know how..

Comment: "Clean" is a dirty word. it has no meaning. It is generally best read as: "I think this looks better; however, I cannot, or refuse, to provide objective reasons for my preference. In fact, I probably have none".

Comment: The point is, passing a single string and expecting the method to figure out what to load based off of that is the opposite of 'clean' - anybody who knows how class loading works would be highly surprised at such an API, given that you can't do that.

Comment: I've edited the question and added what 'I really REALLY just want a string' would look like. I strongly recommend against it.

Comment: So, from what I am gathering, you mean to say it is impossible for code in a jar to know where from where it has been called.? If that's the case, I would agree that passing the input stream is a better solution. I was expecting we would have some way of getting the class name (which you passed as context in second suggestion) in the jar code itself without it being passed as parameter.

Comment: If what I am looking for is not possible, I am going with passing InputStream into the method. Accepting the answer for that's what you suggested. Thanks for you help.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed not possible.